# Does COUNT() run twice?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've this code:

```
"SELECT post_id, COUNT(post_id) AS number_of_votes, (SUM(vote) / COUNT(post_id)) AS result
                                            FROM " . LOG_TABLE . " , $wpdb->posts AS p
                                            WHERE post_id = p.ID
                                            AND p.post_status = 'publish'
                                            GROUP BY post_id
                                            HAVING COUNT(post_id) >= 2
                                            ORDER BY result DESC, COUNT(post_id) DESC
                                            LIMIT 10
                                            "
```

I'd like to know if the COUNT used in the first row run twice?

EDIT: for run twice I mean if it acces the table twice

Best Regards,
Dario

Comment: Can't you check by yourself?

Comment: @LBes how would you test that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unless you are using subqueries of the below form,Table will be accessed only once(if it is what you meant by count, will be accessed twice),so count will be calculated only once and used everywhere

```
select id,(select min(id) from table1 t2 where t1.id=t2.id)b
from
table1 t1
```

Comment: That is wrong! Why did this answer got approved? `COUNT` will be calculated twice, once for each time its being used!

Comment: @sagi:What you are saying is right,i think the user meant if it is accessed from table twice..That is what i mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two `COUNT()` will run twice, but that doesn't mean the row has to be processed twice. For each row of the data the optimizer will set two counters and 1 summing, that shouldn't make any significant difference if using 1 count or two.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,count runs twice indeed.Here's what exactly happens.
This part of code `COUNT(post_id) AS number_of_votes`
counts the total number of post Id's and this part of code `(SUM(vote) / COUNT(post_id))` adds up with the votes which is further divided by total number of post id's.So yes,the count is running twice but the row is not processed multiple times.